# Haskell - Filter, Currying

Tags: haskell, filter, functional-programming, currying

I just want to know if my following understanding about currying functions is correct.
I want to `filter` all elements from a list which are `> 4`. I can achieve this like so:

```
filter (>4) [1..10]
```

1. `(>)` is defined as `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, thats why it cant be bassed to filter.
2. `(>4)` is defined as `(Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool`. The function `(>)` is now curried and still expects one parameter.
3. Because of 2., `(>4)` can be passed to filter.
4. Every List-Element, which is passed to filter, will be passed to `(>4)` and and filter will validate the predicate and return the result.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is more or less correct yes. `(>4)` is equivalent to `\x -> x > 4` or more canonical `\x -> (>) x 4`, so you construct a function that will check for a value `x` if `x > 4`.

Comment: The `(>4)` is *infix operator sectioning*: https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator

Comment: This is correct. You can easily verify all the involved types with ghci: e.g. `:t (>4)    (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool` and `:t (filter (>4))   (filter (>4)) :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
@WillemVanOnsem So one could say _infix operator sectioning_ is an alias for Operator-Currying?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt: no, `(<)` is *always* curried. What you here do is perform *partial application*.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt An *un*curried function is something that is called like this: `f (a1,a2,..,aN)`, taking a tuple of arguments as input. A curried function instead is called like this `f a1 a2 .. aN`, and can be partially applied as `f a1`, `f a1 a2` and so on. This has almost nothing to do with `(>4)`, which is Haskell special section syntax for `\x -> x > 4`. Note that this section is very different from the partial application `((>) 4)`, which would instead be equivalent to `\x -> 4 > x`, reversing the comparison (!)

Comment: Seems like you got it right, aside from slightly improper use of terminology (which others have pointed out).  It might be helpful to observe `(> 4) 5` evaluates to `True` ; `(> 4) 3` evaluates to `False`.  `5 > 4 = (> 4) 5 = (5 >) 4 = (>) 5 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is more or less correct. `(>)` is a function with signature:

```
(>) :: Ord a => a -> (a -> Bool)
```

so it is a function that (like any other function in Haskell) takes *one* parameter, and here returns a function `a -> Bool`.

The problem is thus that if we would use `filter (>) [1,4,2,5]`, then we would make a call `(>) 1`, and this would thus return a function `a -> Bool`, but a `filter` can not work with that, it requires a function that takes an element from the list, and returns a `Bool`, not a function that returns a function that maps to a `Bool`.

We thus can for example use:

```
filter ((<) 4) [1,4,2,5]
```

Here we thus perform [*partial application* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) of the function. This thus means that we generate a function `(<) 4 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool`. We thus can filter with that function, it will thus return `[5]`.

We can also make a function with a lambda expression to "swap" the order of the parameters:

```
filter (\x -> (>) x 4) [1,4,2,5]
```

Here for a value `x`, we will thus call `((>) x) 4`, and this will thus return a `Bool`.

Since it happens often that one of the two sides of an infix operator is provided a value, Haskell has [sectioning syntax for an infix operator [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator):

> - `(2^)` (*left section*) is equivalent to `(^) 2`, or more verbosely `\x -> 2 ^ x`;
> - `(^2)` (*right section*) is equivalent to `flip (^) 2`, or more verbosely `\x -> x ^ 2`

So we can rewrite the last expression to:

```
filter (> 4) [1,4,2,5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Willem. One more question: If I use ghci do determine the signature of (>) like so:
`:t (>)` Iam getting: `(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` and not  `(>) :: Ord a => a -> (a -> Bool)` like you do. Why is that?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt: because `(->)` is a *right associative* operator, so `a -> b -> c` is  equivalent to `a -> (b -> c)`, as is explained here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt There's no difference, `a1 -> a2 -> ... -> aN` is the same as `a1 -> (a2 -> (a3 -> ... aN))))`. GHCi won't print the redundant parentheses but you can pretend they are there.